# Copy a file in all subdirectory with chmod in bash

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh

In Bash

I'm trying to find a way to copy a file in all subdirectory with the good `chmod` :

Example :

> toto.txt is in /home/a

but in a , we can find 3 `dir`

> " b , c , d "

I want to copy `toto.txt` in b, c ,d without deleting `toto.txt` from a.

Comment: `for dir in b c d; do cp /home/a/toto.txt "$dir"; done`

Comment: You mention `chmod` twice, did you mistake it for a tool to copy files, or do you expect to change the permissions on the files?

Comment: Well , thanks for your answers !

As Aaron said , i mention chmod , will it be possible to change the permissions of "toto.txt" depending of directory's permissions ?

Example : toto.txt in b will have 777
                toto.txt in c will have 755 because c has 755 chmod ?

Answer (score 0):

This will copy the toto.txt into all sub-directories found under `/home/a`

```
cd /home/a && for i in *
do
[ -d $i -a "$i" != ".." -a "$i" != "." ] && cp toto.txt "/home/a/$i/"
perm=$(stat -c "%a %n" xadmin/ | awk '{ print $1 }')
chmod $perm "/home/a/$i/toto.txt"                            
done
```

If will only copy the file if the target is a directory `-d` and the file dir is not `.` or `..`, which is the current and the parent dir.

Comment: Thanks very much! I was aware that `$(...)` syntax had some problems with e.g. filenames containing `*`. Your link makes it clear, so I changed my code corresponding to it and will use for my future scripts. 
That's what I like about SO!!!! :)

Comment: I got another read for you: http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes#Prevent_field_splitting_and_ignore_glob_pattern_characters :-)

Comment: I just bookmarked some of those pages for evening study. E.g. "Bash Pitfalls" looks very informative. Always thought my bash skills are good, but I see they are sometimes just inaccurate. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks ver much cb0 ! 
As i mentioned ,
will it be possible to change the permissions of "toto.txt" depending of directory's permissions ? Example : toto.txt in b will have 777 toto.txt in c will have 755 because c has 755 chmod ?

Comment: Yes it is. I extended the the script to include the appropriate chmod command.
First get the octal permission from the directory using stat. Then set the permission to the copy inside the sub-dirs.